# Pub-Sub framework of ZMQ. How to connect to multiple port

Tags: c#, zeromq

Say there will be three (can be any number) of publisher (running on different Exe) and they  publish to 127.0.0.1:1234,127.0.0.1:1235,127.0.0.1:1236 respectively.

Currently, I can connect Pub-Sub by using

```
subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:22223");
```

How do I be able to connect to 3 subscribers. Sorry I read the guide and they say I can do that using subscriber.Connect which I tried by fail

Comment: I guess you need another connect call like this, I have seen such code, can't able to recall. Try it out please.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before and it seems to overwrite the first connect

Comment: Please post some more of your code so we can actually figure out what you might be doing wrong.  `connect`-ing a single subscriber socket to  multiple bound publisher sockets should work just by making multiple calls to `connect` with the appropriate IP:port for each call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [ZeroMQ documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-connect):

> With the exception of ZMQ_PAIR sockets, a single socket may be
>   connected to multiple endpoints using zmq_connect(), while
>   simultaneously accepting incoming connections from multiple endpoints
>   bound to the socket using zmq_bind().

So this should be possible and if it's not, it might be due to a problem with the implementation you're using. The following example using [NetMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq) works for me:

```
private static NetMQContext _context = NetMQContext.Create();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread publish1 = new Thread(() => Publish(5000));
    Thread publish2 = new Thread(() => Publish(5001));

    publish1.Start();
    publish2.Start();

    Subscribe();
}

private static void Publish(ushort port)
{
    using (NetMQSocket socket = _context.CreatePublisherSocket())
    {
        socket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:" + port);

        while (true)
        {
            socket.Send("Hello from " + port);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

private static void Subscribe()
{
    using (NetMQSocket socket = _context.CreateSubscriberSocket())
    {
        socket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
        socket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5001");
        socket.Subscribe("");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(socket.ReceiveString());
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
Hello from 5000
Hello from 5001
Hello from 5000
Hello from 5001
[...]
```